# Not receiving any error on unspecified interface object types when compiling

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, type-hinting, vue-composition-api

Hi I'm testing out the Vue composition API with Types

I'm trying to get an error when an `interface` does not meet the `types` specified for that interface.

I'm successful in implementing the interface/types that are being expected and I get auto suggestions from my IDE so it looks like it works, but when compiling I don't get any errors when trying to pass let's say a `number` to a `string` type.

Here I provide a simple sample

**Vue file:**

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <h1 class="flex justify-center">Test View</h1>
    <TestComponent
      :dataset="{
        strCustomerName: 12345,
      }"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestComponent from "@/components/TestComponent.vue";
</script>
```

This Vue file is just importing a component and sending with it an object named dataset.

**Test component**

```html
<template>
  <h1 class="text-9x1 flex">Hello {{ props.dataset.strCustomerName }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from "vue";

type FormType = {
  strCustomerName: string;
};

interface FormProperties {
  dataset: {
    type: FormType;
    required: true;
  };
}

const props = defineProps<FormProperties>();

console.log("We are props: ", props.dataset);
</script>
```

Then with this test component, I am trying to tell Vue that I am expecting a dataset object to be passed as a property in the `FormProperties`, I'm then trying to tell Vue that I want a certain structure from that object which is the `FormType` where the problem in the example above is that `strCustomerName` is set to be a `string` but when I'm passing a `number` it just goes straight through without any error. I can even pass a key that is not there like if I wanted to use the view file like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <h1 class="flex justify-center">Test View</h1>
    <TestComponent
      :dataset="{
        strCustomerHasAName: 'please give me an error'
      }"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import TestComponent from "@/components/TestComponent.vue";
</script>
```

So basically why am I not getting an error when passing wrong types? or keys that are not defined in the `FormType` object?

Is this the normal behavior or can I actually do something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `defineProps`

The *type declaration* for `defineProps` specifies only the type of every prop, so in your case, `defineProps<FormProperties>()` tells Vue to create a prop named `dataset` that has two fields:

- `type`, which is of type `FormType`, which has a `strCustomerName` property, which is a `string`.
- `required`, which is of type `true` (i.e., it can only be `true`, and any other value would result in an error).

It looks like you were actually trying to use the *runtime declaration* with `defineProps`, but that must be given as a *function argument* to `defineProps`:

```js
import type { PropType } from 'vue'

defineProps({
  dataset: {
    type: Object as PropType<FormType>,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

Or if you'd rather use the type declaration, update `FormProperties` to contain only the data fields:

```js
type FormType = {
  strCustomerName: string;
};

interface FormProperties {
  dataset: FormType;
}

defineProps<FormProperties>();
```

You can't mix the two. `defineProps` receives *either* the type declaration, *or* the function argument, not both.

### Detecting the error

If you used [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) (the official VS Code extension for Vue), you would've seen an error for your original code:

[image: Template error shown in VS Code]

Or if you used [`vue-tsc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tsc) for typechecking, you would've seen the error in the console:

```bash
$ vue-tsc --noEmit
src/components/MyComponent.vue:2:52 - error TS2339: Property 'strCustomerName' does not exist on type '{ type: FormType; required: true; }'.

2   <h1 class="text-9x1 flex">Hello {{ props.dataset.strCustomerName }}</h1>
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in src/components/MyComponent.vue:2
```